# How to store consumer secret for two-legged OAuth provider?

Tags: security, oauth, password-protection

I'm implementing the provider side of a two-legged OAuth protocol for API authentication. We will provide the consumer with a consumer key and secret, which they will use to sign requests. The 2-legged OAuth is dictated by an interoperability standard, and thus a requirement.

The secret is sort of akin to a password, and I would never normally store a password as plain text (bCrypt or similar would be my normal choice). But because my provider needs access to the plain-text secret to verify the signature, it has to be either in some plain-text or reversible form.

I've considered the following options:

#### Store the secret as plain text

It's the most obvious solution, but if the database is compromised somehow, then all of the secrets will have to be changed. To me this solution is not ideal because it has all of the problems of storing a password in plain-text.

#### Apply reversible encryption (e.g. AES) with an encryption key stored elsewhere

This will provide some security, because if the database is compromised then the secrets will still be safe. But reversible encryption requires an encryption key, and the key has to be stored on the server. It means that if an attacker compromises the machine, then the encryption can be circumvented.

Is there something I haven't thought of?

**Clarification** Effectively it's using 2-legged Oauth as a single-signon system. The 'consumer' creates a request including the consumer key, a nonce, and several other parameters. The whole request is then signed by computing an HMAC-SHA1 with the consumer secret. When the request reaches our provider system, the process is repeated and if the signatures match then the request processing continues. We therefore need the plain-text secret to compute the HMAC-SHA1 signature on our side too. Unfortunately this mechanism is dictated by the industry-standard protocol that we need to comply with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761458/correct-way-to-safely-store-token-secret-etc-from-oauth). I'm not an expert on the topic, but I think you're missing part of the equation. In addition to the consumer key and secret, you'll be verifying the application that's sending the request (using an x509 certificate if you're using RSA-SHA1).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the RFC, and that other post seems to have some good info in it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the provider needs the plain text password?

If this is the case then you simply can't have a 'customer secret'.  As soon as the customer discloses this secret to someone else (including you) it fails to become a secret any longer.

Maybe if you explained more of what you are trying to do we could come up with a more elegant appraoch.